# Проблема с CSS (nth-of-type)

Tags: html, css, css3

Имеется примерно следующая конструкция:

```
<row class="tripleRow inverse">
    <div class="container collomn-fix">
        <div class="col-sm collomn-fix">
            <div class="block-tovar">
                Наполение
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm collomn-fix">
            <div class="block-tovar">
                Наполение
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 collomn-fix">
            <div class="block-tovar">
                Наполение
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</row>
```

Хочу покрасить фон поочередно, использую следующее:

```
.block-tovar:nth-of-type(even)
{
    background-color: @BGColorOne;
}
```

Но увы ничего не происходит. Делаю через Brackets, он даже подсвечивать не хочет. Без псевдокласса всё нормально, а с ним не видит. Пробовал писать просто `row.tripleRow .block-tovar` так он тоже не видит. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что данный селектор рассчитывает индекс элементов на одном уровне внутри контейнера.

То есть, сейчас блоки с классом *block-tovar* являются единственными элементами в контейнере. Правило говорит, поменять цвет у элемента с четным индексом.

Так как в контейнере *один* элемент, индекс у него 1 - нечетный, и селектор не применяется.

```css
.block-tovar:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<row class="tripleRow inverse">
  <div class="container collomn-fix">
    <div class="col-sm collomn-fix">
      <div class="block-tovar">
        Наполение
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm collomn-fix">
      <div class="block-tovar">
        Наполение
      </div>
      <div class="block-tovar">
        я четный
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 collomn-fix">
      <div class="block-tovar">
        Наполение
      </div>
      <div class="block-tovar">
        я четный
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</row>
```

Comment: Точно. Об этом я и не подумал. Нужно больше высыпаться)

Comment: @BwehaaFox, если ответ помог - отметьте его решением!

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko Отметил бы сразу, не будь задержки перед возможностью отметки правильного ответа.